# is there a iniherit "<td>" selector?

Tags: html, jquery-selectors, html-table

in a minesweeper i made, i created a 10*10 `<table>` and gave the `<td>`s `id`s 0-99. however i would like to know if there is a inherit selector for each `<td>`, like some sort of html5, or jquery syntax.

### my code

```
document.getElementById("grid").innerHTML = "";

var gameBox = "";

    //ten rows
for ( i = 0 ; i < rowAmount ; i++ ) {
    gameBox += "<tr>";
        //ten columns
    for ( var j = 0 ; j < columnAmount ; j++ ) {
            //produce id value
        var idValue = ( i * rowAmount ) + j;
            //write cell
        gameBox += "<td class = 'box' id = '" + idValue + "' ></td>";
    }
    gameBox += "</tr>";
}
document.getElementById("grid").innerHTML = gameBox;
```

Comment: You mean to select all TDs at once (or some subset)?

Comment: for that i believe you must give id to each td....and then select using that id....since you r trying to select specific td

Comment: @iBlue yeah.... that what i did, so ur answer is "no".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to use CSS to select a td in a row (row) and a column (col) you can use

```
$('tr:nth-child(['+ row +'])>td:nth-child(['+ col +'])');
```

of since you know its a 10 by 10 then you can select the correct td under the table using simple maths - something like

```
$('table.grid td:nth-child('+ row*10 + col +');
```

Comment: is there also some sort of html5 method?

Comment: HTML deals with the mark-up of the elements which is static, CSS3 with the styling of those elements which is mostly static (which you have here). Apart form hover, selection and a few bits they don't deal with dynamic interaction. For dynamic interaction you need a scripting language to assist, even if its just to mark elements with a class once you detect what state they should be in.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do `$('td')` to get all `td` elements though ideally you'd put a class on each of your `td`s you generate and can just select on that so your code doesn't break once you add another `table` somewhere on your page

Comment: i meant to select a specific `td`. and for all `td`s of a table, i would give the table a class and call `$(".myTable td")`